# Importing a txt file in mysql

Tags: mysql, text, import, loaddata

I want to import a txt file in mysql table,and i'm wondering if there is a way to delimitate the data by a character so i can use it as column name.As an example:

My txt file data:

```
Column1=Yo
Column2=Hey
Column3=Wasup
```

I need to use the string until '=' as column name in mysql:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3

 Yo       Hey      Wasup
```

And also how to avoid importing the data between '[]' ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the only built-in command to import a file is [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), which can load a file that represent the table this way:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
Data1,Date2,Date3
```

Example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'yourfile.csv' INTO TABLE YourTable;
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```